# What can be said about the map $K(n)_\ast(X) \to K(n)_\ast(\tau_{\leq n}X)$ when $X$ is a finite complex?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Ravenel and Wilson [showed](http://web.math.rochester.edu/people/faculty/doug/mypapers/emspace.pdf) that $K(\mathbb Z / p^j,q)$ is $K(n)$-acyclic for any $q \geq n+1$, and that $K(\mathbb Z, q)$ is $K(n)$-acyclic for $q \geq n+2$. It follows that $K(A,q)$ is $K(n)$-acyclic for $q \geq n+2$ when $A$ is finitely-generated.

From here, a Serre spectral sequence argument reveals that the map $\tau_{\leq m} X \to \tau_{\leq n+1} X$ (where $\tau$ is Postnikov truncation) is a $K(n)$-local equivalence for all $m \geq n+1$ when $X$ has finitely-generated homotopy groups. (For $\pi$-finite spaces, $\tau_{\leq m} X \to \tau_{\leq n} X$ is in fact a $K(n)$-local equivalence, as observed by [Carmeli,Schlank, and Yanovski](https://arxiv.org/abs/1811.02057)).

It's tempting to conclude that $X \to \tau_{\leq n+1} X$ is a $K(n)$-local equivalence for any $X$ with finitely-generated homotopy groups, but this can't possibly be true. If it were true, then in particular $X \to \tau_{\leq n+1} X$ would be an equivalence for all simply-connected finite spaces $X$. Then we could conclude $K(n)_\ast(S^2) = K(n)_{\ast+n+1}(\Sigma^{n+1} S^2) = K(n)_{\ast+n+1}(pt)$, which is false.

Indeed, according to [Bauer](https://arxiv.org/abs/0803.3798), the convergence of the spectral sequence for the Postnikov tower of $X$ only holds when $X$ is $n$-truncated. This leads to my

**Question:** If $X$ is a space with infinitely many nontrivial homotopy groups, is there any meaningful relationship between $K(n)_\ast(X)$ and $K(n)_\ast(\tau_{\leq n} X)$ or $K(n)_\ast(\tau_{\leq n+1} X)$? (Beyond the mere existence of a map -- for all I know, this map is zero!) How about if $X$ is finite? Or perhaps, what if $X$ is $(n-1)$-connected?

Comment: You do have the Serre Spectral sequence, but I'm not sure how helpful it is

Comment: I wouldn't think that there is any meaningful relationship. For $E$ stable, there is an equivalence $L_{K(n)} \tau_{\ge k} E \simeq L_{K(n)} E$, so that all of the information that $L_{K(n)}$ (or $K(n)_*$) sees is attached to the "germ at infinity" of $E$ (a memorable slogan credited to Dwyer). Since the parts of $\Sigma^\infty_+ X$ and $\Sigma^\infty_+ \tau_{\le k} X$ near infinity can be arbitrarily far apart without *very* strong hypotheses on $X$, their $K(n)$-homologies are not likely to bear any particular relation.

Comment: You *can* make pretty strong statements about what $K(n)_* \tau_{\le k} X$ looks like, though, which you might find separately interesting: http://www.math.jhu.edu/~wsw/papers2/math/32-finite-postnikov-H1R8W-1998.pdf .

Comment: I don't know a good answer, but I suspect that this could be a fruitful area to investigate.  One possible approach: the above comments tell us about $K(n)_*(\Omega^\infty X)$ for $X$ in the thick subcategory generated by $H=BP\langle 0\rangle$, and some of the proofs can be given in terms of the Bousfield-Kuhn functor $\Phi_n$ which satisfies $\Phi(\Omega^\infty X)=L_{K(n)}X$.  So you can proceed to investigate $K(n)_*(\Omega^\infty X)$ when $X$ is in the thick subcategory generated by $BP\langle m\rangle$ with $m>0$, using the theory of Wilson spaces.

Comment: @NeilStrickland Neil and others:  I wrote a long paper on the Morava K-theory of infinite loopspaces [Adv. Math. 201 (2006), 318-378].  It is quite definitive, and, yes, does use the $\Phi_n$ functors.  Folks are encouraged to look at this to get a sense of weird stuff that can happen.

Comment: @EricPeterson It seems to me that the analogous statement for unstable connective covers is that $\tau_{\geq m} X \to \tau_{\geq n+1} X$ is a $K(n)_\ast$-equivalence, but this doesn't extend to lower connective covers. Instead, the sequence $\tau_{\geq m+1} X \to X \to \tau_{\leq m} X$ (which is the same for all $m \geq n$) is a kind of fundamental decomposition of $X$, both parts of which are potentially interesting -- though as HRW point out in the paper you linked to, there's a strong tendency for the truncated part to split uninterestingly.

Comment: er --  $\tau_{\geq n+1}$ should be $\tau_{\geq n+2}$ and $m \geq n$ should be $m \geq n+1$ in my comment

Answer (score 6):

Let me make more concrete a comment I already wrote. In [Adv. Math. 201 (2006), 318-378], my example 2.22, illustrating a theorem just before it when $n=1$, says that, for any spectrum $Y$, there is a short exact sequence of Hopf algebras over $K(1)_*$ as follows:
$$ K(1)_*(\mathbb PY) \rightarrow K(1)_*(\Omega^{\infty}Y) \rightarrow K(1)_*(\tau_{\leq 2}\Omega^{\infty}Y).$$
Here $\mathbb PY$ is the free $E_\infty$--algebra generated by $Y$: the wedge of all the extended powers of $Y$.

So if $X = \Omega^{\infty}Y$, then $K(1)_*(X) \rightarrow K(1)_*(\tau_{\leq 2}X)$ is onto.  One could wonder if one has an epimorphism for other $X$.  Okay, lets try something else: Bousfield gave a cute short argument that if $X$ is $E_*$--acyclic, so is $K(\pi_j(X), j)$ for any $j$. So if $X$ is $K(1)_*$--acyclic, so is $\tau_{\leq 2}X$, and thus our map is still an epi.

This is enough fun for one answer, so I'll leave things here.

Comment: Great, thanks! It's good to at least know that this map is decidedly nonzero for a good class of nontrucated spaces. Btw, where can I find Bousfield's cute argument?

Comment: @TimCampion See [Bousfield, A. K.
On homology equivalences and homological localizations of spaces.
Amer. J. Math. 104 (1982), no. 5, 1025–1042.]  The cute idea: $SP^{\infty}$ preserves homology isomorphisms.